# Is WebClient the best way to download http data?

Tags: c#

Problem: I need to download hundreds of images from different hosts. Each host has anywhere between 20-hundreds of images.

Solution: using a `new WebClient` every time a image needs to be downloaded through the WebClient's `DownloadData` method.

Or would be better to keep a pool of open socket connections and making the http request using lower level calls?

Is it expensive to open/close a tcp connection (I'm assuming that is what WebClient does), so that using a pools sounds more efficient?

Comment: Best code is code that achieves results you need without errors in a time you need. So can you comment on what needs improvement compared to your current code (assuming you've done estimates how fast you can download images and your current code downloads slower than your goals but have some room to improve till you hit network limits).

Comment: I should have added that speed is of the highest concern.

Comment: I suspect you have "can I outrun speeding car if I run faster" kind of question... Did you measured how fast you can download images, how fast you are downloading them now, what is your performance goal - do you need to download them faster than your connection allows? It will be hard for you to find answers if you don't know what problem you are trying to solve (and even if you have problem). Unless of course you just doing it purely for fun - than go to lowest level and do everything yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the underlying infrastructure which `WebClient` uses will already pool HTTP connections, so there's no need to do this. You may want to check using something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) of course, with some sample URLs.

Fundamentally, I'd take the same approach to this as with other programming tasks - write the code in the simplest way that works, and then check whether it performs well enough for your needs. If it does, you're done. If it doesn't, use appropriate tools (network analyzers etc) to work out *why* it's not performing well enough, and use more complicated code only if it fixes the problem.

My experience is that `WebClient` is fine if it doesn't what you need - but it doesn't give you quite as much fine-grained control as `WebRequest`. If you don't *need* that control, go with `WebClient`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think WebClient would used a pool. I'll have to check that out with wireshark.  Also I read your book which was very good!

Comment: @user261490 Jon's book is amazing, but this comment isn't relevant to the question.Please try to make your comments relevant to the question or the answer so it would be helpful for others

Comment: @user261490 Jon is right on here.  One thing to consider is looking into the [parallel libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) from MS in combination with whatever you choose.  This will allow you to download on multiple threads, limited by bandwidth of course.  Make sure you Close() the connections when you are done too... I made that mistake once.

Answer (score 0):

I use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to scrape anything I want. Unless, of course, there are services available for the requirement, but even though, sometimes, there are limitations (business limitations) and I often prefer to dig the html from pure http request. Sometimes just make feel more like developer, you know...

Comment: You haven't given any reason *why* you use `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`, which makes this answer less useful than it might otherwise be.